# Two UIButton form one having gradient color and another having border and rounded corner

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, gradient

[image]

I am trying to achive this using gradient color and corner radius on **[.topLeft,.bottomLeft]** and  **[.topRight,.bottomRight]** but I am not able to achieve the border color on one side.

Here is my code

```
//btnMale gradient color
btnMale.roundCorners([.topLeft,.bottomLeft], radius: 20)
btnFemale.roundCorners([.topRight,.bottomRight], radius: 20)
btnMale.backgroundColor = .clear
let gradient1: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.view.frame.size.width - 90)/2 , height: btnMale.frame.size.height)
gradient1.colors = [Colors.appYellow,Colors.appRed].map { $0.cgColor }
gradient1.startPoint = GradientOrientation.horizontal.startPoint
gradient1.endPoint = GradientOrientation.horizontal.endPoint
btnMale.layer.insertSublayer(gradient1, at: 0)
btnMale.applyGradient(withColours: [Colors.appYellow,Colors.appRed], gradientOrientation: .horizontal)
btnMale.borderWidth = 0.0

btnFemale.borderWidth = 0.5
btnFemale.borderColor = .black
btnMale.setImage(UIImage(named: Images.imgMaleIconWhite), for: .normal)
btnFemale.setImage(UIImage(named: Images.imgFemaleIconBlack), for: .normal)
```

and here is my output

[image]

Please help.

Comment: An off-topic suggestion: wouldn't you like to use `UISegmentedControl` for this purpose? you could also apply layer styling to the whole element instead of distinct buttons.

Comment: @AuRis any example? or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pradip it's better to add buttons in UIView. It will be easy for you to manage. I made UI like you want using UIView. See this,

```
let button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 250, width: 200, height: 100))
    button.setTitle("HI", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnTapped(pageNo:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 50, y: 250, width: 250, height: 50))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(view)

    let btnMale = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    btnMale.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 125, height: 50)
    btnMale.setTitle("Male", for: .normal)

    btnMale.applyGradient(colours: [UIColor.yellow,UIColor.red])


    view.addSubview(btnMale)

    let btnFemale = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    btnFemale.frame = CGRect.init(x: 125, y: 0, width: 125, height: 50)
    btnFemale.setTitle("Female", for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(btnFemale)

    view.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    view.clipsToBounds = true
```

Output of above code will look like this.

[image]